# macOS: "SF Pro Text" not available on new computer

Tags: appkit, nsfont, nsfontmanager

I want to use the "SF Pro Text" font in my app. It works fine when I build my app on my main computer (running macOS11 Big Sur), but I have a 2nd partition to run macOS Monterey, and it doesn't seem to be available there at all, whether through Interface Builder or through code (using NSFontManager). Using this returns nil on my Monterey partition:

```
NSFont* boldFont = [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] fontWithFamily:@"SF Pro Text" traits:NSFontWeightBold weight:8 size: 16.0];
```

What gives? Do I have to install the font manually? I thought it would come with the system, since it is a 'system font'?

Answer (score 2):

You can install it manually, it's available [here](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/)
If you install it specifically for your user, you'll find it in YourUser/Library/fonts.